# How much heigth can a roll of pipe insulation cover?

Tags: geometry

I'm getting a bit confused on calculating how much insulation I need to buy.

Here are the specs of the insulation:

Dimensions: $1.5''\times 24''\times 25'$

Packaging: $50$ square feet per roll

The diameter of the pipe is $4''$.

So, putting everything in inches and using the surface area of a cylinder formula

$$2\pi \times 2(2+h)=600$$

$$12.566 h= 574.8$$

$$h\approx45 \space \text{inch}$$

Now to check,

$$A=2πrh+2πr(2)=2·π·2·45+2·π·22≈590.61942$$

And that seems right, however that package of insulation can definitely cover more than 45 inches of 2" radius pipe. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 50 ft² = 7200 in²